# How Addthis works in opencart and Which values it uses to share on facebook?

Tags: opencart2.x, addthis

I am  using opencart 2.1.0.1

I have a question that, how AddThis plugin works on opencart product page.

Which product details it use to share on Facebook.

On my opencart website, when I share product link on Facebook with Addthis

plugin that time it share product meta tag title as title but description value

going to change from product to product. it means for product A taking product

description for product B taking meta tag description and also it is not

updating while sharing.

Comment: For facebook sharing using:[share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#example)

Comment: But can I share values that I want?